# find kth missing element in a contiguous array (time limit exceeded)

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

Given an increasing sequence a[], we need to find the K-th missing contiguous element in the increasing sequence which is not present in the sequence. If no k-th missing element is there output -1.

The first line consists of an integer T i.e. the number of test cases. The first line of each test case consists of two integers N and K.Next line consists of N spaced integers.

Input

5 2

1 3 4 5 7

Output
6

As the first missing element is 2 and the 2nd(kth) missing element is 6.

I am getting run time error `Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorTime Limit Exceeded` for the following solution :

```
while(t > 0){
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    int b[] = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    int sub=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++){ 
        sub = a[i+1] - a[i];
        if(sub != 1){
            b[j] = a[i] + 1;
        }
      } 
    }

    if(b[0]==0)
        System.out.println(-1);
    else  
        System.out.println(b[k-1]);

    t--;
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to reduce the loops and improve run time complexity. Can anyone help me out how to do it.

Comment: *"I am getting run time error for the following solution"* - what error? What is the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: "I am getting run time error", "it is working fine for the sample testcase". These are contradictory statements. Is it working or not?

Comment: How is this solution supposed to work? Does it actually work or have you gotten an error every time? What exactly is your error message?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void findNthMissingNum(int[] nums,int n){

    int low = 0;
    int high = nums.length - 1;

    while(low  < high){
        if(high - low == 1){
            System.out.println(nums[low]+n);
            break;
        }
        int mid = low + (high - low)/2;

        int missingOnLeft = nums[mid] - nums[low] - 1;
        int presentOnLeft = mid - low - 1;

        if(n > missingOnLeft - presentOnLeft){
            //go right
            low = mid;
            n -= (missingOnLeft - presentOnLeft);
        }else{
            //go left
            high = mid;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the function you would want:

```
static int kmissing(int n, int k, int[] set){
    int[] a = set; //create array
    int i = 0; //create iterator
    if(a[n-1]-a[0]-n+1 < k) return -1;//check if no solution and return -1
    while(a[++i]-a[0]-i<k);//find first value that goes past result
    return k+a[0]+--i;//return the valid result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public int kthMissingOptimizedLogN(int[] nums, int k){
        int s =0;
        int e = nums.length-1;
        int totalMissinCount = nums[nums.length-1]-nums[0]-(nums.length-1);
     //check if total missing numbers are less than k, then kth missing number is not present in array
        if (k > totalMissingCount)return -1;
        while(s<e){
            int m = s+ (e-s)/2;
            int missingCount = nums[m]-nums[0]-m; //total missing count between mid and start, k is less than count, go left
            if(missingCount>=k){
                e = m;
            }else{
                s = m+1;
            }
        }
return nums[s-1]+k-(nums[s-1]-nums[0]-(s-1)); // after while loop s-1 points to lower bound index for k meaning your missing number should be between s-1 and s index.
  }
```

Comment: Can you share OJ link? I can submit and check against all cases.